# How can we add footer to bootsfaces datatable?

Tags: jsf-2.2, bootsfaces

I am trying to add a footer to my bootsfaces datatable in my web application.

```
<f:facet name="footer">
    <b:commandButton value="Create Tyre" icon-awesome="plus" look="primary"
               actionListener="#{tyreMasterController.prepareCreate()}"
               update=":TyreMasterCreateForm" oncomplete="PF('TyreMasterCreateDialog').show()">
     </b:commandButton>
</f:facet>
```

The command button or anything else doesnot show up. Please help in this

Comment: Can you please reference the documentation which states you can use a `footer` facet on a `b:dataTable`?

Comment: Sorry, i dont have any such document.

Comment: So, what made you think that it was possible to do? Just add your button below the table.

Comment: @Jasper .. well that is just so obvious if the footer is not available in bootsfaces. I thought there may be a workaround to achieve this